# Get id of the MongoDB document created in a Symfony3 repository

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, symfony, doctrine-odm

In my **Symfony3** project, I do have some documents such as **User**, described below:

```
UserBundle\Document\User:
    repositoryClass: UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository
    fields:
        userId:
            id: true
        email:
            type: string
        firstName:
            type: string
        lastName:
            type: string
```

Some time, I want to create a user document through the user repository.
Working around the *createQueryBuilder()*, I have built this method:

```
public function insert($email, $firstName, $lastName)
{
    $data = array('email' => $email,
        'firstName' => $firstName,
        'lastName' => $lastName,
    );

    /* Create query */

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder();

    /* Add Data */

    $query
        ->insert()
        ->setNewObj($data);

    /* Return */

    $query
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();

    return true;
}
```

Rather than returning `true`, I would like to **return the Id of the document I have just created**.

Looking for answers, I found this piece of code:

```
$this->getDocumentManager()->getConnection()->lastInsertId
```

Unfortunately, it is not returning what I am looking for:

```
object(MongoDB)[307]
  public 'w' => int 1
  public 'wtimeout' => int 10000
```

Thanks for your help !

EDIT:

Here is an updated code with the suggestion made in the accepted answer:

```
public function insert($email, $firstName, $lastName)
{
    $id = new MongoId();

    $data = array(
        '_id' => $id,
        'email' => $email,
        'firstName' => $firstName,
        'lastName' => $lastName,
    );

    /* Create query */

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder();

    /* Add Data */

    $query
        ->insert()
        ->setNewObj($data);

    /* Return */

    $query
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();

    return $id->__toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to generate the identifier upfront by calling `new \MongoId()`, adding it to data you're inserting (under `_id` key) and return known value. Also this is exactly what underlying MongoDB driver does behind the scenes when you're inserting a document without identifier set explicitly (see [this doc example](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php#refsect1-mongocollection.insert-examples))

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB driver writes the ID into the array that is being passed in, but you're not seeing it due to the structure of the query objects. You can get it from the query object that is returned by `getQuery()`:

```
$query = $queryBuider->getQuery();
$query->execute();

$id = $query->getQuery['newObj']['_id'];
```

Note however, that this won't necessarily work in future versions, since the new MongoDB driver (which will be used starting with ODM 2.0) doesn't have this functionality.